# SQL Azure Query taking 5 minutes to run - Fast when minor modifications are made to the query - FullTextSearch

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT TOP (10) *
FROM [User] this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN [VenDetails] vendordeta2_ ON this_.Id=vendordeta2_.CustomerId
AND vendordeta2_.DeletedOn IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AppDetails] applicantd3_ ON this_.Id=applicantd3_.CustomerId
AND applicantd3_.DeletedOn IS NULL
WHERE this_.DeletedOn IS NULL AND
   this_.discriminator='Customer'
  AND CONTAINS(this_.UserSearch, '"Michael*" AND "Bill*"')
ORDER BY this_.CreatedOn DESC
```

Which is taking 5 minutes to run.

The query is fast if I remove one of the WHERE clauses. E.G removing

```
this_.DeletedOn IS NULL
```

OR

```
this_.discriminator='Customer'
```

Means the query executes sub 1 second.

I don't see any missing indexes, and I don't get the same behaviour on premises SQL server, only with Azure.

Edit Adding Query Plans:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLIze.jpg

Comment: have you  looked at the query execution plans for the different cases, that is to say with and without the same search criteria.  Have you got an index with all 3 search fields in it?

Comment: try an index on {discriminator, DeletedOn , UserSearch}

Comment: UserSearch is a little long for an index, but its a full text index anyway which I thought was enough.

i see a difference in the plans, but not sure on way forward.

Comment: does the change in the plan change any lookups to scans?

Comment: Hi Andrew - added a link to query plans: http://imgur.com/a/PW9if

Comment: have you tried an index on discriminator, DeletedOn ?

Comment: or try a filtered index on IS NULL and ordering by discriminator https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/09/filtered-indexes-and-is-not-null/   or an index other way around from what I said before

Comment: Yes that's there. Its the second Nested Loops where the plans diverge.